# How to correctly send html to using cURL using Mandrill API in bash?

Tags: json, bash, api, curl, mandrill

I'm struggling with trying to send an email through Mandrill API using cURL. For some reason, the command is not seen as a valid JSON action. I've tried the following as indicated on a website:

```
Backspace is replaced with \b
Form feed is replaced with \f
Newline is replaced with \n
Carriage return is replaced with \r
Tab is replaced with \t
Double quote is replaced with \"
Backslash is replaced with \\
```

Replaced double quote with single quote. Nothing works.

This is the HTML template: `https://pastebin.com/BN7FMStg`

This is my code:

```
curl -H -A "Mandrill-Curl/1.0" -d '{
  "key": "XXXXXX",
  "message": {
    "html": "<b>Hi there!</b>",
    "subject": "Just testing",
    "from_email": "noreply@mydomain.com",
    "from_name": "MyName",
    "to": [
      {
        "email": "rex@mydomain.com",
        "type": "to"
      }
    ],
    "return_path_domain": "mydomain.com",
    "important": false,
    "track_opens": false,
    "track_clicks": false,
    "async": true
  }
}' 
'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json'
```

I don't have any ideas left. If anyone has a full working example and a explanation so I can understand for myself, it would be great.

Comment: From the example https://www.mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.curl.html#method=send ```"html":"<p>Example HTML content<\/p>"``` It looks like that you may need to escape `/`, in you case: ```"html": "<b>Hi there!<\/b>",```. Give it a try, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was that I was escaping the double quotes in a wrong way. "\ instead of \". Everything works fine now. Hope this helps others too. I have just replaced " with \". That's all I had to do in my case. Wasted half a day on this.